# how to spwan recursive calls and for loop iterations in multiple threads in java (if possible)?

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, spawning

I was wondering if it is possible to spawn each `loop iteration` (each `iteration` into a `thread` by itself) and finally collect the result. consider this example, nothing fancy in it at all. Just a simple `for-loop`, but the idea is to extend on it. The body of `for loop` does not matter, I just filled up with some code. but basically assume it has some expensive calculation which will take few minutes to complete for each iteration. so I want to do each loop calculation in a separate thread.

```
public class Threadspawns {

    private double[] arr = new double[4];

    public void calculations(){
        for (int i =2; i < 6; i++){
                   //expensive calculation
            arr[i-2]=Math.pow(i,500);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Threadspawns t = new Threadspawns();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t.calculations();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t.arr));
        System.out.println("time taken "+ (end-start));

    }

}
```

on the same note, 
if it is possible to actually split the `recursive calls` into multiple threads and collect them as they return.
Example is that of fibonacci

```
public static int fibonacci(int n){
        if (n==0)
            return 0;
        if (n==1)
            return 1;
        return fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1);
    }
```

It is possible that it cannot be done for fibonacci recurive method. but any other example of paralleling recursive calls between threads IF POSSIBLE would be nice to know.

P.S: I have basic knowledge of `Thread and Runnable`, but wondering if the above is doable

Comment: I dont think recursive calls can be spawned to different threads.

Comment: It can be done but it's a bad idea because you'll need a lot of threads and the thread limit is way lower than the recursion limit if you call just methods.

Comment: @zapl: It is interesting to know that it can be done. can you elaborate as how it can be done. though its a bad idea, it is good to learn.

Comment: You can recursively spawn threads, though as zapl points out it's a bad idea.  A more robust solution would be a runnable queue with a worker thread pool, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: Ok it's harder than I imagined. I'm trying to come up with a solution revolving around [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Comment: @Taylor: pools are different and my question has different aspect.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706048/using-threads-and-recursion-in-java-to-calculate-fibonacci-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Arf that accepted solution is way too simple. But it does the job.

Comment: @user1988876 if you elaborate on why a threadpool won't work, perhaps I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your first requirement that is moving the expensive calculation into a Callable task. Hope it find it useful:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Threadspawns {
    private final int THREAD_COUNT = 8;
    private final int CALCULATION_COUNT = 60000;
    private double[] arr = new double[CALCULATION_COUNT];

    public void calculations() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        ExecutorCompletionService<Double> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Double>(executorService);
        for (int i = 2; i < CALCULATION_COUNT; i++) {
            completionService.submit(new Calculation(i));
        }

        //Get from all Future tasks till all tasks completed
        for (int i = 2; i < CALCULATION_COUNT; i++) {
            try {
                arr[i] = completionService.take().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //do something
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //do something
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Calculation implements Callable<Double> {
        private final int num;

        private Calculation(int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        @Override
        public Double call() throws Exception {
            return Math.pow(num, 500);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threadspawns t = new Threadspawns();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t.calculations();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t.arr));
        System.out.println("time taken " + (end - start));
    }
}
```