# The cost of a recursion. Recursion = multi-core calculations? Or it will only take more memory (RAM)?

Tags: recursion

If we use bubble sort or insertion sort then processor uses 1 core for calculation? Because I've already known about Merge Sort and power of recursion. Recursion make it possible to do many things at one time.
 And I'm wondering if we use Merge Sort than processor uses more than one core for calculation? 
Or recursion will only take more memory (RAM)?

Comment: How can you predict how many cores a code can use :/

Comment: Recursion = function calls in function call = more calls on the call stack = more RAM needed. Calculations in the function = CPU powr required. More function calls = more CPU power required.

Comment: Thy! @Jankapunk

Comment: You're welcome, but notice, that more CPU Power does NOT mean more CPU-cores! If you want to implement a threaded recursion you may read on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706048/using-threads-and-recursion-in-java-to-calculate-fibonacci-numbers